# Making HVAC duct flush with floor

Tags: ducts

I removed a interior wall with a heat/A/C duct in it. I need to lower into floor. I currently stands about 8 inches from floor. What do I need to do in order to make flush with flooring?

Comment: Can you include some photos of the duct?

Comment: Watch out for asbestos wrap (looks kinda like cardboard) on the duct.

Comment: Yeah, it's hard to say anything specific with the limited information provided. Please update your question with a better description and/or photos.

Answer (score 1):

Typically the duct run is finished off with one of these, depending on the orientation of the pipe under the floor and IF in this case the pipe leading to the wall duct is round.

[image: hvac1]
[image: hvac2]
[image]

If the duct is rectangular under the floor, the idea is pretty much the same, it needs to transition from the duct size under the floor to the grill size in the wall but for the floor location.

Comment: They are called boots.